# PHP cannot find a LESS file on WAMP, but can on server

Tags: php, less, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to use lessphp on WAMP for local development. I'm trying to preprocess a particular *less* file on WAMP that is right next to the PHP file, but PHP throws errors saying it cannot find my "input.less" file. When I upload the same set of files to my server, PHP can find the *less* file and preprocess it just fine.

Is there a setting in my WAMP's php.ini that I need to change for it to be able to find files?

My php file:

```
<?php
    require "lessc.inc.php";
    $less = new lessc;
    $input = "input.less";
    $less_code = file_get_contents("input.less");
    echo $less->compile($less_code);
?>
```

My *less* file:

```
div {
    border:5pt red dashed;
}
```

The offending error:

```
( ! ) Warning: file_get_contents(input.less) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\Freelance\server\wamp\www\theming\wp-content\themes\spiralkit\header.php on line 51
```

Comment: can you try using ./lessc.ini.php ?

Comment: Just provide the full path to the less files!!

Comment: Just gave it a whirl; The less.inc.php including works just fine, and it will process any less that I throw at it, even on my WAMP server. Php just can't find the "input.less" file to parse.

Comment: @OneTrickPony That works on my local WAMP server, but then I have to replace that when I go live. Is there not a way to have PHP know how to find a relative file path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the actual __ DIR __ constant in PHP.

__ DIR __ : The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned.

PS: Remove the whitespaces

Comment: Finally, it worked out.

`$location = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "input.less";`

Thanks so much!